# Should I close my DBHelper on onStop()?

Tags: android, android-database

I have followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and now have my own DB Contract and DB Helper classes. I have DBHelper variable in Activity and I set it in `onCreate()`

```
mDbHelper = new CustomDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

my question is: should I close the dbHelper in `onStop()`, or is it unnecessary?

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first

        mDbHelper.close();
    }
```

Comment: Youu should close it in onDestroy. Best to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not declare it in `onCreate` method.

The most convenient way in this regard is to initialize it when you need to access it. Then use it and close immediately after using. `onStop` or `onDestroy` are not assured to be called. So its not good to handle this kind of resource in these methods.

So, if you need to use it three times in your application initialize it three times also close three times. Its good for application development from memory management's view also.

Comment: So you suggest making it a local variable? As I understand close() is called when it gets out of scope without any reference pointing to it

Answer (score 0):

the onStop() method in an Activity **may never be called**, in low memory situations where the system does not have enough memory, it will simply kill your Activity after its onPause() method is called. [Android Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop())

Generally we can recycle resources in onDestroy(), however, it's not guaranteed to be called either.

Comment: if your Activity is killed the OS cleans up everything what was created in that process, otherwise the system would be full of garbage after short time